# SQL server update statement getting Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
UPDATE Newchat
 Set [Answered] = (Select b.[Answered]
      From Table1 b
      where  Newchat.CHAT_ID = b.[Chat ID]
      and Newchat.Chat_Date >= '2017-Feb-22' and Newchat.Chat_Date <= '2017-Feb-28');
```

Whenever I'm running this code all rows of [Answered] are getting Null except this dates.
Please suggest someway.

I also tried applying filter "Newchat.[Answered] is not null"

```
UPDATE Newchat
     Set [Answered] = (Select b.[Answered]
          From Table1 b
          where  Newchat.CHAT_ID = b.[Chat ID] and Newchat.[Answered] is not null
          and Newchat.Chat_Date >= '2017-Feb-22' and Newchat.Chat_Date <= '2017-Feb-28');
```

This too doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no match, you get `NULL`.  Presumably you really want:

```
UPDATE nc
    Set [Answered] = b.[Answered]
    From NewChat nc join
         Table1 b
         on nc.CHAT_ID = b.[Chat ID] and
            nc.Chat_Date >= '2017-Feb-22' and nc.Chat_Date <= '2017-Feb-28';
```

This only updates the rows that match the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You have two queries going on here.  The inner one (inside the brackets) is supplying the data for the outer one which is doing the update.  Your problem is that the *inner* query is restricted by dates, so it only supplies values for those dates.  But the outer query updates *all* rows - with `NULL` where there is no data from the inner query.

Keeping close to the way you have set out your query, moving the date restrictions outside the brackets should give you what you want - like this:

```
UPDATE Newchat
 Set [Answered] = ( Select b.[Answered]
      From Table1 b
      where  Newchat.CHAT_ID = b.[Chat ID] )
 WHERE Newchat.Chat_Date >= '2017-Feb-22' and Newchat.Chat_Date <= '2017-Feb-28';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Newchat SET [Answered] = b.[Answered]
From Table1 b
WHERE Newchat.CHAT_ID = b.[Chat ID] AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Newchat.Chat_Date,'2017- 
02-22') <= 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Newchat.Chat_Date,'2017-02-28') >= 0
```